# TypeScript, RequireJS and custom RequireJS module paths

Tags: visual-studio, requirejs, typescript

I'm using TypeScript in VS2015, and trying to import the knockout module in some other module. Knockout is installed to a path other than "/knockout", in fact, all my "libraries" are installed to "/app/lib". As a result of the folder names not necessarily matching the module names, I've defined the following in my `main.ts`:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "/app",
    paths: {
        "text"       : "lib/requirejs-text/text",
        "durandal"   : "lib/durandal/js",
        "plugins"    : "lib/durandal/js/plugins",
        "transitions": "lib/durandal/js/transitions",
        "knockout"   : "lib/knockout.js/knockout",
        "jquery"     : "lib/jquery/jquery",
        "bootstrap"  : "lib/bootstrap-sass-official/javascript/bootstrap"
    }
});
```

So my app at runtime can find knockout using just `var ko = require("knockout")`.

However, at design time in visual studio, I get a "red squiggly" under my `require()` call:

[image]

I believe this is because VS is trying to use paths rather than my custom path configuration to look for Knockout. How then, can I tell VS about my custom path configuration so this works? At the moment the generated JavaScript is:

```
var receiveDeliveryViewModel = (function () {
    function receiveDeliveryViewModel() {
        this.deliveryReference = ("");
    }
    return receiveDeliveryViewModel;
})();
```

Which as you can see does not reference Knockout.js.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [type definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/knockout) for Knockout:

This will provide type information for Knockout and also solve the import error you are seeing.

Also available via NuGet (other package managers are available)!